# Difference between type I error and p-value in normality tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption

What is the difference of type I error (false positive probability) and p-value in normality tests?
Also, how should I interpret the values of FPP to see whether null hypothesis is rejected for a specific significance level?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [P-value vs Type 1 Error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158351/p-value-vs-type-1-error)

Comment: The meaning of "type I error" and "significance level" is the same for hypothesis tests in general -- nothing changes for normality tests in particular. I will point you to a relevant Wikipedia page, but unfortunately a page with more correct discussion (which explained the small distinction between the level of a test and the type I error rate rather than just stated them to be the same thing) no longer seems to be there. Nevertheless, this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors#Error_rate should be sufficient to clarify some of your misunderstandings of terminology.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @Pitouille, the discussion was helpful, however, still I am not sure how to use fpp values to reject/accept null hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @Glen_b. I found the link you sent helpful. However, still I am not sure how to reject/accept a null hypothesis based on fpp value. Should I treat FPP in a similar way as p-value here? I mean if fpp is smaller than significance level, the normality test get rejected and vice versa.

Comment: The significance level ($\alpha$) is the threshold that you fix to reject or not the null hypothesis. If you obtain a p-value lower than the significance level, then you are in a position to reject the null hypothesis. However,  you have to keep in mind that you are working with samples... and you might have a sample that does not represent well your population. You might reject the null hypothesis while it is actually true... This is the type I error (false positive).

Comment: @Aep [Statistical hypothesis testing: The testing process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing#The_testing_process)

Comment: See also [Comparing and contrasting, p-values, significance levels and type I error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33453/805) and perhaps  [Misunderstanding a P-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/166327/805) may be of some value as well.